# If an animal tiles the plane via translation, can it do so in a lattice configuration?

Tags: integer-lattices, tiling, tessellations, polyomino

It is known that if a polyomino tiles the plane using only translated copies, then it has at least one such tiling where the centroids of each tile form a lattice; see for instance the paper [*Arbitrary versus periodic storage schemes and tessellations of the plane using one type of polyomino*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995884800078). (In fact, this result extends to topological disks with piecewise $C^2$ boundary and a finite number of inflection points; see [*Tiling the plane with one tile*](http://jolivet.org/timo/docs/BN_onetile.pdf), by D. Girault-Beauquier and M. Nivat.)

I am curious whether this result holds if we relax the connectivity requirement on polyominoes, and consider arbitrary *animals* in the plane, i.e. finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Are there any animals which tile the plane via translation, but only in an anisohedral manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the answer to this question turns out to be trivial. Consider the simplest possible disconnected animal: two squares separated by a distance of 2.

```
 _____        _____
|     |      |     |
|     |      |     |
|_____|      |_____|
```

This animal tiles the plane by translation, but any such tiling must within a horizontal line have tiles whose $x$-coordinates go $n, n+1, n+4,n+5,n+8,n+9,\ldots$, and so cannot form a lattice.

However, if we relax to *periodic* tilings, the answer to the title question turns out to be yes - every finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that admits a tiling does so in a periodic manner, as proven in [Bhattacharya 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05738.pdf). (Credit to [this post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/10/08/the-structure-of-translational-tilings-in-zd/) of Terrence Tao's for alerting me to the existence of this paper.)

Comment: If it was permitted to shift this animal by half a unit of the underlying square grid then it does admit a lattice tiling. Place animals in a row at $\{\dots,0,4,8,\dots\}$. This fills alternate squares in the row. Place the next row one half unit down at $\{\dots,1,5,9,\dots\}$. Then another half unit down at $\{\dots,2,6,10,\dots\}$, and another half unit down at $\{\dots,3,7,11,\dots\}$. Repeat in the obvious way. I expect that there will still be fairly simple animals for which even this type of approach will not be possible.